# Python- Module not having defined attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, attributes, definition

The new code is --

game.py

```
from globalized import *
"""need to fix events file"""
game = True
while game is True:
       print(location[1])
       events1()
       for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
              print(i + 1, t[0])

       choice = int(input("Enter location: "))
       location = transitions[location][choice - 1]
```

from globalized.py

```
from events import *

start = ('start', 'the starting room')
common_room = ('common room', 'a room for socializing')
storage_bay = ('storage bay', 'a room used for storage')
cross_way = ('cross way', 'A way that parts into multiple rooms')
engine1 = ('engine room 1', 'A room with an engine for powering the ship')
engine2 = ('engine room 2', 'A room with an engine for powering the ship')
bridge = ('The bridge', 'a walk way that tran sends into a mysterious room')
dead_room = ('Mysterious room', 'this room is filled with dead')
elevator = ('elevator', 'a lift that takes you to different places')
sick_bay = ('sick bay', 'A room for storing sick')
storage_bay1 = ('storage bay', 'a room used for storage')
gallery = ('Gallery', 'a room')
bed_room = ('bed room', 'a room used for sleeping')
bridge_2 = ('the bridge', 'used for moving to new areas')
labroatory = ('lab', 'Used to make science')
captain_q_1 = ('captains quarters east', 'where the captain sleeps')
captain_q_2 = ('Captains quarters west', 'where the captain eats')
bath_room = ('bathroom', ' a place for other stuff')
pick_up = ('Pick-up bay', 'a bay for getting goods')

location = start
transitions = {
       start: (common_room,),
       common_room: (start, storage_bay, cross_way),
       storage_bay: common_room,
       cross_way: (common_room, engine2, engine1),
       engine1: (cross_way, bridge),
       engine2: (cross_way, sick_bay),
       bridge: (engine1, elevator, dead_room),
       dead_room: (bridge,),
       sick_bay: (engine2, storage_bay1, elevator),
       storage_bay1: (sick_bay,),
       elevator: (bridge, sick_bay, gallery),
       gallery: (elevator, bed_room, bridge_2),
       bed_room: (gallery,),
       bridge_2: (gallery, labroatory, captain_q_1),
       labroatory: (bridge,),
       captain_q_1: (bridge, captain_q_2, bath_room),
       bath_room: (captain_q_1,),
       captain_q_2: (pick_up, captain_q_1),
       pick_up: (captain_q_2,),

}
```

from events.py

```
from random import randint
from globalized import *

def events1():
    if location == engine1:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An arrow hits you")
        else:
            pass
    elif location == engine2:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An enemy lunges at you")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

this is the error on the running of this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ayden/PycharmProjects/untitled10/game.py", line 1, in <module>
    from globalized import *
  File "C:\Users\Ayden\PycharmProjects\untitled10\globalized.py", line 1, in <module>
    from events import *
  File "C:\Users\Ayden\PycharmProjects\untitled10\events.py", line 4, in <module>
    location = start
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

so heres an explanation of what im trying to do...
I took almost all the code in the game.py file and took it to the globalized file then took imports from only events as not to create a loop. But where ever i place the location = start piece of code i get an error as it is not defined. I understand why as if i put it before the definition of the places it has nothing to set equal too and if i put it after the event already ran not having the room location so it errors again. How can i fix this?

Comment: Please post the full error message and the minimal code to reproduce it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ayden/PycharmProjects/untitled10/game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import events
  File "C:\Users\Ayden\PycharmProjects\untitled10\events.py", line 1, in <module>
    from game import *
  File "C:\Users\Ayden\PycharmProjects\untitled10\game.py", line 53, in <module>
    events.events1()
AttributeError: module 'events' has no attribute 'events1'

Comment: while game is True:
    print(location[1])
    events.events1()
    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print(i + 1, t[0])
    choice = int(input("Enter location: "))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]

Comment: from game import *
from random import randint


def events1():
    if location == engine1:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An arrow hits you")
        else:
            pass
    elif location == engine2:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An enemy lunges at you")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

Comment: Thanks for the updates ... but please edit them into the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing in the wrong module, you should import events in the game module, instead of importing game in the events module.

In other words add this code to beginning of the game file:

```
import events
```

And remove this from the beginning of the events file:

```
from game import *
```

Once you do this you run into more problems, you should learn about passing variables between functions.

Edit:

The problem now is that you are importing events in game and at the same time importing game in events. This is creating a loop.

I believe you should remove "from game import *" and instead pass all the variables you need to the events function. You can put all location variables in a dictionary and pass the entire dictionary.

You can pass the variable and dictionary you need like this:

In game: change "events.events1()" to "events.events1(location, dictionary_name)"

And in events: change "def events1():" to "def events1(location, dictionary_name):"

Comment: That import is already in the game file.  Each file uses objects from the other, so removing an import will leave those items undefined.

Comment: Yep, he must have edited his post to add the import events. It wasn't there at first.

Comment: how do you mean like i make them into the dictionary and then do 'from game import dictionary_name"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a circular dependency, as @Thomas pointed out:
**game** depends on **events**; **events** depends on **game**.

You need to refactor this structure.  I recommend that you raise your global items to another file that is included from both **game** and **events**, such as file **game_global.py**.  This leaves your two code files looking like below.

game.py:

```
from game_global import *
import events

while game is True:
    print(location[1])
    events.events1()
    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print(i + 1, t[0])
    choice = int(input("Enter location: "))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]
```

events.py:

```
from random import randint
from game_global import *

def events1():
    if location == engine1:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An arrow hits you")
        else:
            pass
    elif location == engine2:
        check = randint(1, 10)
        if check > 5:
            print("An enemy lunges at you")
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
```

The code runs in this state.

Comment: okay but can you better explain what i should do in game_global so i imported from both files is that right so far? what should i do next or is that all?

Comment: Game global is simply the stuff I took out of game.py

Comment: did you do it like say i took out the engine i would do in game global engine = game.engine?

Comment: No, the **import** statement in **game.py** imports everything from **game_global.py**.  You don't alter anything in moving it from **game** to **game_global**; just put the same statements there, and use them in **game** and **events** as if they were declared locally.

Comment: I did actually run your code after this change.  I used the numbered choices to move from one room to another, got the descriptions, etc.

Comment: now im getting an error saying events1 is not defined

Comment: so its like a plain copy and paste or take them out of game entirely and then put them in game global

Comment: Right.  Do that, update the **import** in each of your original files, and you're good to go.

Comment: okay where do i place locations initial definition i cant find a good spot to where it is defined for the events.py and it can be used by game.py any suggestings

Comment: I stuck it in game_globals, and it worked fine.  If you put it elsewhere, make sure that you set it to *something* in game_globals, just to get it declared properly.

Comment: did you put all of the places definitions like start = ('start', 'the start') and then the transions in game_global as well? since when i put it in game_global i sitll get an error

Comment: Yes.  Everything I took out of **game**, I put into **game_global**.  "An error" is not enough information to help, especially as I no longer have your original code or my modifications.

Comment: okay im gonna modify the uqestion to have my new code and the error